# Datepicker looks terrible in ie7

Tags: css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

I added jQuery UI datepicker to site and it works good in all browser but ie7. Check it out please: http://test.skoldin.pp.ua/contacts.html (two top inputs in header).

I use standart jQuery UI css theme which on jQuery UI site looks good in IE7.

Comment: Not sure where the question is in this.. But at this point IE7 is being used by less than 1% of internet users so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I'd love to don't worry about it, but IE7 support is demands of customer.

Comment: I meant no offence by my answer. If you really need to support IE7 though. I am sure your would be able to style it with css using the class
.lt-ie8 .ui-datepicker

Comment: I wonder why css theme which looks great in IE7 on jQuery UI site, looks bad on my one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because IE7 doesn't loaded styles for jQuery UI from Google CDN. I've copied those styles to my localhost and it works in IE7 now.